# cell/column width in Excel Office.js

Tags: javascript, excel, office365

The latest Javascript Api for Excel makes working with worksheets much easier, but I seem to miss the ability of setting a cells width in code. Range objects have a format property, but that only supports font sizes and borders and such.

What am i missing? I'm inserting dates into columns from a task pane add-in, but the default cell width means that the user only sees '####' and has to manually resize the cells.. not very nice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use Range object to set the width as

```
range.format.columnWidth = 130;
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the [autofitColumns](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/rangeformat#autofitcolumns) function:

```
range.format.autofitColumns();
```

The only time I don't like this function is when I have so much data in one cell that it stretches the cell to be wider than the screen, which makes horizontal scrolling miserable. In that case, I go with @shyam_'s answer:

```
range.format.columnWidth = 130;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am glad to know that you like the new JavaScript APIs for Excel. Actually we are releasing a new wave of APIs for Excel which will include the set column width and a lot of other new exciting features including worksheet protections, sort/filter and so much more. Check it out on [GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/ExcelJs_1.2_OpenSpec/excel).

If you want to try out the new APIs, make sure you have the latest Office 2016 for Windows or Office365. Here are the instructions

1. With in your add-in, in HTML, replace the existing Office.js script reference with

   ```
     <script src=" https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ```
2. If you want IntelliSense for a even more delightful coding experience, go to Scripts/References/_references.js, remove the last two entries, and instead replace them with

`/// <reference path=" https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js" />`

Thanks,
Sky

Microsoft

Comment: hot! any info as to when 1.2 will be officially released?